# Access static fields directly instead of calling a static getter method, is it faster?

Tags: java, android, dalvik, performance

I'm writing an Android app and I have a class that generates and maintains some fixed URL's that can occasionally change. I keep them all in one class called UrlUtils:

```
public class UrlUtils {
  private static String sUrlBase = "http://google.com";

  /**
   * Called occasionally
   */
  public static void refreshUrlBases() {
        sUrlBase = "http://yahoo.com/" + new Random().nextInt();
  }

   public static String getUrlBase() {
        return sUrlBase;
   }
}
```

I have to make a lot of calls to `getUrlBase()` above, so I was thinking about making `sUrlBase` public and access it directly. Will this approach be better in terms of performance?

Comment: Keep to good design practices unless you've profiled your app and you know that this getter call is taking up a disproportionate amount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not going to change your url more frequently, then instead of `getter/setter` method I will say that you can keep `static` directly

```
public static String google_url = "http://google.com";
public static String yahoo_url  = "http://yahoo.com";
```

In keeping `static` method, it may happen that due to some problem `static` `setter` values are `removed`(reset to original). So, in that case it will return you the `original` constant of `static` value.

**UPDATE:**

If your are going to update your `URL` `dynamically` then `static` `method` would prove to be better option.

```
    public static String sUrlBase = "http://google.com"; 

    public static String getsUrlBase() {
        return sUrlBase;
    }
    public static void setsUrlBase(String sUrlBase) {
        this.sUrlBase = sUrlBase;
    }
```

Comment: I need to dynamically generate the URL in `refreshUrlBases()` so this wont work. (Editted the example code to reflect this.)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, for performance reasons you should avoid use of getters and setters. Here is a tip from android "[Designing for performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#internal_get_set)" doc.

> Without a JIT, direct field access is about 3x faster than invoking a
>   trivial getter. With the JIT (where direct field access is as cheap as
>   accessing a local), direct field access is about 7x faster than
>   invoking a trivial getter. This is true in Froyo, but will improve in
>   the future when the JIT inlines getter methods.

Comment: Now Proguard optimization is fairly built-in to the Android SDK. I'm sure Proguard will inline the getter, so, you'd have the best of both worlds with the optimizer.

Comment: At the very top of that page it also says "Optimize Judiciously", only optimize if you know there's a problem.

Comment: @Sean: I couldn't find a single reference in http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#internal_get_set about Proguard. Do you know where I can find out about the optimizations that Proguard does?

Comment: @Sean Couldn't find anything that suggests getters and setters are optimized by Proguard. Have a look at the link sent by Yury.

Comment: Did you see "Inline methods that are short or only called once."?

Comment: @Sean That's right! This changes everything. So with the Android SDK and default Proguard settings getters and setters should be inlined?

Comment: This is nearly exactly the default config that the Android SDK generates: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/proguard.cfg  It disables some optimizations, presumably because they don't play nice with dex, but leaves this one on it seems. I've been using Proguard with Barcode Scanner since Android 0.9 and it definitely inlines.

Comment: Right. So it seems odd that they've suggested avoiding internal getters/setters in that performance article!

Comment: (They're actually talking abou avoiding virtual method invocations, which this is not.) I know this article has existed since before Android 1.0 so imagine it's partly just a hold-over. It is still good practice since Proguard is not enabled unless you bother to and most people don't know about it. It also can't always figure out what it can inline so if it mattered you'd want to know to do it by hand.

Comment: I do not think that they just have given us expired information. They consider JIT in their article and it has appeared since Android 2.2. So I consider this article as a quite new best practices.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference. You should use whatever method is easiest for you. Usually you should use getters and setters for readability and code practices.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would not worry too much about performance for small simple data like URL as in this case, and so for that matter whether it is direct field access or access using methods will not bother me much. 
The case where it will makes difference for me is when frequency of getter calls is so high that it is affecting overall response.
My concern will be regarding changing the value accidentally [bugs :( ] since the field has public static access. When accessed through getter/setter at least there is one place where I can do some checks.

Comment: That is my main worry too. But seems the performance advantage is too big to neglect in some cases at least.